# HSA Contribution selection

Tags: united-states, taxes, hsa

I am using the software Taxact to do my tax return for 2016. I got HSA from my previous company. The ratio is 1:1, which means I contributed one dollar and the company matched one dollar.
Now I have two debit cards, one is for me(my name is printed on the card), the other is for my spouse(spouse's name is printed on the card).

I meet the question below.

[image]

H is my name, u is my spouse name.I chose the first one. But which one is the correct choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to have additional users with their own debit cards on a single account. If you have one account, and two users with their own card sharing the same account, then you should choose the second option- contributions were made only to your account. If you each have your own account, then you would choose the option you selected. If you aren't sure, you should be able to look at one of your statements or call the number listed on the back of your card to clarify if a single account is being shared.